# Concatenate strings using transform

Tags: pandas, string, concatenation, transform

I have a dataset like the following

| Job | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | Qual1 |
| ABC | program1 |
| ABC | element1 |
| DEF | Qual2 |
| DEF | program2 |
| DEF | element2 |
| FGH | Qual3 |
| FGH | program3 |
| FGH | element3 |
| IJK | Qual4 |
| IJK | program4 |
| IJK | element4 |

I want to group and transform such that the value becomes a string with format Qual*Program.Element

For this example it will become:-

| Job | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | Qual1*program1.element1 |
| DEF | Qual2*program2.element2 |
| FGH | Qual3*program3.element3 |
| IJK | Qual4*program4.element4 |

I got inspired by the below code(which works by concatenating the strings with ',') I found this on Stackoverflow

```
df['Value']=df.groupby(by=['Job'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: ",".join(x))
```

And this is what I tried and it is not working!!

```
df['Value']=df.groupby(by=['Job'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: x[0]+'*'+x[1]+'.'+x[2])
```

I get a key error for this. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a Series in your lambda. `x[0]` looks for the row labeled 0, which likely never exists or only exists for the first group (where the first row of your DataFrame *happens* to be a row labeled 0).

Without changing much, if you want to select the first, second, and third rows within each group use `.iloc` to reference them. Also no need for transform if you want one result per group in the end.

```
df.groupby('Job')['Value'].agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0]+'*'+x.iloc[1]+'.'+x.iloc[2])
```

---

```
Job
ABC    Qual1*program1.element1
DEF    Qual2*program2.element2
FGH    Qual3*program3.element3
IJK    Qual4*program4.element4
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. I was dropping duplicates after the result. You have made it much easier. I thought it was a list.